# How to pass an argument into a workflow activity in code?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I am using Windows Workflow Foundation 4.5.

I want to pass an argument into a WriteLine activity. Code as below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WriteLine wf1 = new WriteLine();
        wf1.Text = "arg1";

        Dictionary<String, Object> arg = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
        arg.Add("arg1", "Hello,world!");

        WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(wf1, arg);
    }
}
```

But I get the following error at runtime:

> ```
> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: The values provided for the root activity's arguments
>  did not satisfy the root activity's requirements:
> 'WriteLine': The following keys from the input dictionary do not map to arguments and must be remove
> d: arg1.  Please note that argument names are case sensitive.
> ```

So what's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the argument is "Text". This will work:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WriteLine wf1 = new WriteLine();

        Dictionary<String, Object> arg = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
        arg.Add("Text", "Hello,world!");

        WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(wf1, arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I understand why the input argument is of the type  Dictionary< String, **Object** >. This way, i can pass any types into the workflow with mapping to the name of its public properties.